# Function to return result of asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, promise

I have a [plugin](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) on my website that gets a user's Facebook login status. Using my own function `facebookStatus()` I want to return the user's Facebook ID. So far I have tried three approaches:

## 1.

```
console.log(facebookStatus()); // Should show the Facebook ID in the console

function facebookStatus() {
  facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function(response) {    
    var result = response.authResponse.userID;
  }, function(error) {
    var result = error;
  });
  return result;
}
```

this yields

> Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined

I am guessing this is due to the asynchronous nature of `getLoginStatus()`.

## 2.

```
function facebookStatus() {
    facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function(response) {    
        return response.authResponse.userID;
    }, function(error) {
        return error;
    }).then(function(response) {
        result = response;
    });
    return result;
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(...).then is not a function

## 3.

```
facebookStatus().then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});

function facebookStatus() {
    return facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function(response) {    
        return response.authResponse.userID;
    }, function(error) {
        return error;
    });
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: facebookStatus(...).then is not a function

PS: I am using jQuery, if it helps.

Comment: 1. No, the error occurs because `result` is not defined. `var` introduces variables in the function scope, so outside of the function in which you introduce the variable, it's not defined.
2. and 3. `then` is a function which is defined for Promises, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then .

Comment: Thanks, I have now tried `return new Promise(facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function(response) { ... }`, but that returns `Uncaught TypeError: Promise resolver 1 is not a function`

Comment: Yes, because that's not how promises work. You would have to rewrite the function to work.

Comment: Is there no way to take that `facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus()` and 'wrap' or turn it into a promise function?